MatPlotLib FuncAnimation: Is there a way to show the gif as it saves?
I am currently experiencing an issue where I can either run an animation in Jupyter Notebook, or I can save it, but I can't do both. If I want to do both, I have to run the code twice, once with:
ani.save('fast.gif', writer=PillowWriter(fps=60))
and once without (to print to the output in Jupyter Notebook). Is there a way to have it both print to the output and save to a gif at the same time?
This is how I'm running the animation:
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, init_func=init, frames=len(t), interval=2, blit=True, repeat=False)
Followed by the ani.save command above, so it looks like:
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, init_func=init, frames=len(t), interval=2, blit=True, repeat=False)

ani.save('fast.gif', writer=PillowWriter(fps=60))

plt.show()

Once the animation is done running, it'll save but not starting with the original data. If I save it first then run, the animation similarly starts but not at time = 0. Is there any easy fix for this?

It is hard to follow your last paragraph: " it'll save but not starting with the original data. If I save it first then run, the animation similarly starts but not at time = 0."  What do you mean by 'it'll save but not starting with the original data'? And you don't share any code, and so we cannot check and see what you mean about ' animation similarly starts but not at time = 0'. See How do I ask a good question?, in particular the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' that stresses including a minimal, reproducible example.

Aside from issues with your post lacking useable code and details in regard to the last paragraph, I'm not following what the goal is here? The title says, "Is there a way to show the gif as it saves?" Do you mean what will be the equivalent content in the gif? Because, of course, you cannot show the gif before it saves. The other thing I'm not understanding is why not just save the animation as gif and then display the gif in the next cell? I don't see why there is need to run the animation code twice as you state.

I'm not sure how to be more clear. When I save, it does not start the gif at time = 0, it starts at time = 30 seconds or however long. It literally just doesn't save from the beginning. All of the code needed is present in the above, this is just about how to save the gif while the animation is also generated in the output of the cell, as it takes a while to save the gif and run it, so you don't have to wait 15 minutes to see the final product. You can think of any animation code, and the question would be the same, because the question is not about the plotting itself.

I wonder if it is the fps part impacting the fact it isn't saving from the start? Did you try without that? Gif saving example here doesn't involve that.
